# Check if fields are edited or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 7 textfields put inside a table. These textfields data i get from server when user presses submit. After filling textfield with fetched data, user submits that data to the server from a new button submit.

If the user submits the data as it is, I need to show an error message that '**at least one field must be edited**'. If it edits at least one field and then submits I will update data on the server.

How can I check whether user has changed a field or not?

Problem is I will need to store data fetched for comparison, which I will have to do it in global variable in my JavaScript (which is not a good practice).

Comment: You could store it using data() in the textfields.

Comment: instead of storing data in global variables, you can create an hidden input(or an data-xx attribute) for each field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an hidden input (like say @lastr2d2) named `haschange` like

```
<input type="hidden" name="haschange" id="haschange" value="0" />
```

and add an jquery or javascript function witch change the value of `haschange` from `0` to `1`
when happens an event `onChange` on each `textfields`. for example you can create a function like bellow:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Check this link 
    $("#textfields1").change(function(){
          $("#haschange").val(1);
    });
});
```

Finally when you click the button of finally submit then you can check if `haschange` value is `0` or `1`

--- Edit --- 
If you want check for original changing (see @antindexer comments) then you can use below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        //Check this link 
        $("#textfields1").change(function(){
             var defaultValue = document.getElementById('textfields1').defaultValue;
             var currentValue = document.getElementById('textfields1').value;
             if( currentValue != currentValue  ) {
                $("#haschange").val(1);
             }
        });
    });
```

Comment: What will happen if I change one value. And change back this value. In this case your code will work as changed. So you should read carefully the question.

Comment: Can you show me where exactly hi say somthing like that please?

Comment: "Problem is I will need to store data fetched for comparison, which I will have to do it in global variable in my JavaScript (which is not a good practice)." <- Here. It means that he actually he want to save all previous data and check it then.

Comment: ok then. I am editing my answer

Comment: @antindexer check again my answer!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

Add data attributes to your input fields. Replace "<%= serverValue %>" with whatever syntax your server code uses.

```
<form id="form">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="<%= serverValue %>" data-original-value="<%= serverValue %>" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

And then place a script tag on the page with something like this (assuming you're using jQuery):

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    var $form = $('#form');
    $form.on('submit', function (e) {
      $(form).find('[data-original-value]').each(function (index, el) {
        var $el = $(el);
        if ($el.val() === $el.attr('data-original-value]')) {
          e.preventDefault();
          console.log('please edit at least one value');
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Here is a JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/X4S4y/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use attr `data-value` ( or any name you want ) to keep your original value

Example: ( Assume you use PHP )

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $value_1?>" data-value="<?php echo $value_1?>" class="input_text">
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $value_2?>" data-value="<?php echo $value_2?>" class="input_text">
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $value_3?>" data-value="<?php echo $value_3?>" class="input_text">
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $value_4?>" data-value="<?php echo $value_4?>" class="input_text">
```

In Jquery you can check if there are any change in input text then submit form

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("form").submit(function(){
      var is_changed = false;
      $(".input_text").each(function(){
         if ( $(this).val() == $(this).attr("data-value") {
               return false;
         } else {
              is_changed = true;
         }
      });
      if( is_change == true ) {
         alert("Please change at least one input");
         return false;
      }
  });
})
```